# Simple PHP Login - num_rows

Tags: php

I am using mysql_num_rows to check if one row is returned for my user login and if count == 1 then log user in, I get an error though below my code is after that. Any suggestions?

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/web42001spring09/rcoughlin/public_html/process-login.php
>   on line 13

```
<?php
// include database info
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    // get data from form
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $query  = "SELECT username,password,id FROM login WHERE username=".$username." AND password=".$password." LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count  = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // if 1 then login them in set cookie and redirect
    if($count==1){
        setcookie("password", "".$password."", time()+3600);
        setcookie("username", "".$username."", time()+3600);
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }else{
        echo "Wrong Username or password combination";
    }
}else{
    echo "Must be submitted via form.";
}
```

Not sure why the code is drawing that issue? I have used this method before.

Comment: add a call to mysql_error() after the query and ouput the results
that should give you a better error-message

Answer (score 10):

You're not quoting your strings in the query, so your SQL statement is invalid.

```
$query  = "SELECT username,password,id FROM login WHERE username='" . mysql_escape_string($username) . "' AND password = '" . mysql_escape_string($password) . "' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to add quotes AND use `mysql_escape_string` or `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely don't want to put input straight into SQL!

Answer (score 2):

### Firstly, check for errors...

The "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" because there was an error in your SQL, but you haven't made life easy for yourself by ignoring the failed query. Use [mysql_error][1] to get the error message.

### Secondly, properly escape strings in SQL...

Once you see the error, you'll see you missed some quotes in your query, but you must also escape the strings you put in a query, otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks...

```
$query  = "SELECT username,password,id FROM login ".
    "WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' ".
    "AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
{

    $count  = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // if 1 then login them in set cookie and redirect
    if($count==1){
        setcookie("password", "".$password."", time()+3600);
        setcookie("username", "".$username."", time()+3600);
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }else{
        echo "Wrong Username or password combination";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error:".mysql_error()."<br>;
}
```

Always use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when building a query, or use a wrapper class library which does it for you with parameterised queries, like [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or [ADODb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm)

### Finally, a word on those cookies...

Also, logging someone in by giving them a cookie with the username and password isn't a terribly good way to implement a login. Aside from transmitting the password in the clear with every request, it's highly vulnerable to a cookie theft attempt. Given your naive approach to SQL security, it's likely you'll also be leaving yourself vulnerable to [XSS][5] attacks making it easy for someone to collect those cookies :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might want to do 2 things:

1. Sanitise your input - passing user-submitted data straight into a database query is a recipe for disaster (see [`mysql_real_escape_string(string $unescaped_string)`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)).
2. Put quotes around literals in database queries (i.e. `username ='".$username."'`)

The error message you're getting is due to the fact that the MySQL result object (`$result`) is not valid. Try calling [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/mysql_error) to see what error message MySQL returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  if ($row) { // success
```

Assuming you'd probably want to fetch some columns along with the authentication check (e.g. real name, last login etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Because both `password` and `login` are strings, you need to change the SQL:

```
$query="SELECT username,password,id FROM login WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do never store user authentication data in a cookie!**

Answer (score -1):

The query is invalid (the $result == false)

Line:

```
$query  = "SELECT username,password,id FROM login WHERE username=".$username." AND password=".$password." LIMIT 1";
```

Should be replaced by:

```
$query  = "SELECT username,password,id FROM login WHERE username='".mysql_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_escape_string$password)."' LIMIT 1";
```

The PHP mysql_query() function doesn't give errors by default.
Using a function that shows sql errors allow you to spot these errors easily.

```
function my_query($sql) {
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if ($result === false) {
    trigger_error('['.mysql_errno().'] '.mysql_error(), E_USER_WARNING);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Right now the username and password are injected directly in the sql string.
What you want is `password = "secret"`, now the query contains `password = secret`
Mysql error "unknown column sercet"

PS:
  Using a "LIMIT 1" here is a sign that there are several users (ids) using the same username password combination. (Not recommended)